# How to get attribute values and phone number from Twilio studio flow to twilio flex?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

In my Twilio studio flow I am using send to flex widget in that I am passing values in attributes
but how to use that attributes and phone number in Twilio flex panel 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a call into Flex from Studio, the attributes you set are set as the `attributes` property on the `task` object that wraps the call or message. You can then [access that task and data in the Flex UI using the task Context](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/add-component-context).

Comment: Awesome! Do you mind marking the answer as correct so that other people can see it helped too? Thanks!